# In what scenario it is necessary to use both compile & link function in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is my custom directive in Angular. I am new to angular directives.

```
app.directive('customer',function()
{
var directive = {};

directive.restrict = 'E';

directive.template = "Customer name : <b> {{customer.custName}} </b> , Customer Email : <i> {{customer.custEmail}} </i>";

directive.scope = {
    customer: "=name"
}

directive.compile = function(element, attributes)
{
    element.css("border", "1px solid #f00");
    var linkFunction = function($scope,element,attributes)
    {
        element.html("Customer name : <b>"+ $scope.customer.custName +"</b> , Customer Email : <i>"+ $scope.customer.custEmail+" </i>");
        element.css("background-color", "#ff0");
    }

    return linkFunction;
}

return directive;
```

})

**Why it is necessary to use compile & link function?**

Can someone please explain me what does these things serve in a directive?

```
directive.scope
directive.compile
var linkfunction
```

Answer (score 1):

Now that the transclude parameter is available to the link function (since 1.2 I believe), I don't see much use for the compile function.

While it will let you do work before the link function is processed, it comes at a time that there isn't very much valuable work to be done.  For example, bindings have already been processed.

The fact that scope hasn't been bound yet, might be useful if you're using transclusion and stuck with some version of Angular pre 1.2, but since you can access the transclude function via the link function, now I still don't see much use for it.

As for the purpose of the various directive properties, I would take a look at the [AngularJS documentation page for Directives](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive).

Link functions provide a clean and easy way for us to register event listeners and and manipulate DOM elements.

The scope property allows you to configure the AngularJS scope object that will be used by the directive.  It can take a boolean true (scope is shared with the parent), false (scope of the directive is isolated from the parent's scope), or an object.